# Return SQL SELECT query equals number of rows

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE category=1 AND NUMBER=4 OR NUMBER=10 
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```

I want to receive the result of this query a randomly five lines whose category=1 and number=4, and also a randomly five rows in which the category=1 and the number=10.
So it should be equal (!) number of rows that are specified in the WHERE after AND (five results with a number = 4, and five results with number=10). If, for example, change LIMIT 10 to LIMIT 20, it must be 10 lines with first result and 10 lines with second result. 
If I run written by me query it produces randomly, for example, 7 rows with number=4, and 3 lines with number=10.

Is it possible to implement this, or tell me what I can use to achieve such a result?

Comment: what do you need "LIMIT" for?

Comment: @pskink I want only 10 random rows from all possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for using `union all`:

```
(SELECT t.*
 FROM TABLE_NAME t
 WHERE category = 1 AND NUMBER = 4
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL
(SELECT t.*
 FROM TABLE_NAME t
 WHERE category = 1 AND NUMBER = 10
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 10
);
```

This assumes that each group has a sufficient number of records.

The `rand()` may not be necessary for what you want to accomplish.  If you have large'ish data, then it does add a lot of overhead.